# LCM of two numbers using for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
number1 = 6
number2 = 8
for i in range(1, number1 + 1):
    a = number1 * i
    for j in range(1, number2 + 1):
        b = number2 * j
        if b == a:
            print(number)
```

The compiler is returning 6 as an answer. But my expectation is to get 48

Comment: what is `number` on last `print` statement ? it is not defined in the program

Answer (score 1):

First, the least common multiple of 6 and 8 is 24, not 48, so you should expect to get 24. The issue with your code is that you're returning the original `number1`/`number2`, not the calculated LCM (which is in `a` and `b`). Also, once you reach a result, you should stop both loops immediately because that number is the LCM and any further results will be multiples of the LCM. Try this instead:

```
def lcm(number1, number2):
    for i in range(1, number2 + 1):
        a = number1 * i
        for j in range(1, number1 + 1):
            b = number2 * j
            if b == a:
                return a


print(lcm(6, 8))  # => 24
```

This is fine for a homework assignment, however, this code is inefficient. It is better to use [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to get the greatest common divisor, then use `(number1*number2) / gcd(number1, number2)` to calculate the least common multiple, like this:

```
def lcm(number1, number2):
    a = number1
    b = number2
    while b != 0:
        temp = b
        b = a % b
        a = temp
    return (number1*number2)//a


print(lcm(6, 8))  # => 24
```

Or better yet, as [Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen) pointed out in the comments, use the built-in [`math.lcm()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm) function from the `math` module. Like this:

```
import math

print(math.lcm(6, 8))  # => 24
```

Comment: Also see [`math.lcm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm)

Comment: @MarkTolonen Haha, thanks I didn't even think about that! I've edited my answer to include that (with attribution, of course).